# How to set time between reports of users?

Tags: javascript, php, html, laravel

Is it possible to add a timer between reports of a user?I want to add 5 minutes between the reports of a user, or to make disable the button for reports for 5 minutes, even if the user refresh the page.It is possible?

**Here is my button for report**

```
<li class="share-link" style="float: right;left: 20px"><a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal" href="javascript:void(0)" ><i class="rounded-x icon-flag"></i></a></li>
```

and after that I have a modal which send the report.

**Here is the controller**

```
   public function careerReportCareerSolution(requ $request)
    {
  $reportExists = \App\Reports::where('user_id', $request['user_id'])
            ->whereDate('created_at', '>', Carbon::now()->subMinutes(5)->toDateTimeString())
            ->exists();

            if($reportExists) {
            // report has been created within 5 minutes
            return Redirect::back()->withErrors(['error', 'Report created within the last 5 minutes']);
        }

        $report = \App\Reports::create([
                        'user_id' => $request['user_id'],
                        'username' => $request['username'],
                        'user_id_posted' => $request['user_id_posted'],
                        'username_posted' => $request['username_posted'],
                        'career_solution_id' =>$request['career_solution_id'],
                        'subject' =>$request['subject'],
                        'why_reporting' =>$request['why_reporting'],
                        'why_reporting_message' =>$request['why_reporting_message'],
                        'additional_message' =>$request['additional_message'],
                        'comment' =>$request['comment'],
                        'comment_user' =>$request['comment_user'],
                        'comment_id' =>$request['comment_id'],
                      ]);
                      $id = $request['career_solution_id']; // looks like this is the ID you ar looking for

                      $career = CareerSolution::findOrfail($id);
                      $career->active = $request['active'];
                      $career->save();



        if($report != ""){
            flash('Career solution report submited', 'success');
        }else{
            flash('Career solution report', 'warning');
        }



        return Redirect::back();


    }


    }
```

So, I to set a time between reports, 3-5 minutes a user shouldn't be able to make a report.

Comment: Try storing last report time in session or database, then check current time with it whenever he tries to make report.

Comment: Yes that is possible. You store the time at which a user submits a report(e.g. database), the next time a user submits check the time passed since last submit and if >5 mins, then allow submit, otherwise tell user (s)he cannot yet submit a new report.

Comment: Hey, I'm storing the time of report in `created_at` table.

Comment: @jibsteroos , can you give me an example please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Untested, however assuming you are using timestamps (`created_at`, `updated_at`) on the `Report` table, you should be able to achieve this with the following logic:

```
$reportExists = \App\Report::where('user_id', $request['user_id'])
    ->whereDate('created_at', '>', now()->subMinutes(5)->toDateTimeString())
    ->exists();

if ($reportExists) {
    // report has been created within 5 minutes
    return Redirect::back()->withErrors(['error', 'Report created within the last 5 minutes');
}

...
```

This will check whether or not a report has been created for that user within the last 5 minutes using the `->whereDate()` eloquent query method.

The `->exists()` method is used to find out if there is at least one occurance of the report.

A check is made to see if `$reportExists` is true. If so, the application will redirect the user to the same page with an error message (fill the `->withErrors()` method with the appropriate message).

This should be placed before all other controller logic.

Comment: Thank you.I'm using `Carbon::now()`, but I can still make a report without timer :(

Comment: What are you receiving from `$reportExists`?

Comment: `dd($reportExists)`  is `false`

Comment: In the DB, are you making sure there is a report created within 5 minutes of testing this check?

Comment: Here is my reports from `reports` table . https://imgur.com/a/gWLFj6Q . I made a reports, the page was refreshed, and after that I made another one, after some seconds, with same result :(